# How do you climb up the parent directory structure of a bash script?

Tags: perl, bash, directory

Is there a neater way of climbing up multiple directory levels from the location of a script.

This is what I currently have.

```
# get the full path of the script
D=$(cd ${0%/*} && echo $PWD/${0##*/})

D=$(dirname $D)
D=$(dirname $D)
D=$(dirname $D)

# second level parent directory of script
echo $D
```

I would like a neat way of finding the nth level. Any ideas other than putting in a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dir="/path/to/somewhere/interesting"
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='/'
parts=($dir)
IFS=$saveIFS
level=${parts[3]}
echo "$level"    # output: somewhere
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
ancestor() {
  local n=${1:-1}
  (for ((; n != 0; n--)); do cd $(dirname ${PWD}); done; pwd)
}
```

Usage:

```
 $ pwd
 /home/nix/a/b/c/d/e/f/g

 $ ancestor 3
 /home/nix/a/b/c/d
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without loops would be to use recursion. I wanted to find a config file for a script by traversing backwards up from my current working directory.

`` rtrav() { test -e $2/$1 && echo $2 || { test $2 != / && rtrav $1 `dirname $2`;}; } ``

To check if the current directory is in a GIT repo: `rtrav .git $PWD`

`rtrav` will check the existence of a filename given by the first argument in each parent folder of the one given as the second argument. Printing the directory path where the file was found or exiting with an error code if the file was not found.

The predicate (`test -e $2/$1`) could be swapped for checking of a counter that indicates the traversal depth.

Comment: Beautiful. Added to my `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with including a Perl command:

```
$ pwd
/u1/myuser/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7
```

The first command lists the directory containing first N (in my case 5) directories

```
$ perl-e 'use File::Spec; \
          my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir( \
             File::Spec->rel2abs( File::Spec->curdir() ) ); \
          my @dirs2=@dirs[0..5]; print File::Spec->catdir(@dirs2) . "\n";'
/u1/myuser/dir3/dir4/dir5
```

The second command lists the directory N levels up (in my case 5) directories (I think you wanted the latter).

```
$ perl -e 'use File::Spec; \
           my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir( \
              File::Spec->rel2abs( File::Spec->curdir() ) ); \
           my @dirs2=@dirs[0..$#dir-5]; print File::Spec->catdir(@dirs2)."\n";'
/u1/myuser
```

To use it in your bash script, of course:

```
D=$(perl -e 'use File::Spec; \
           my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir( \
              File::Spec->rel2abs( File::Spec->curdir() ) ); \
           my @dirs2=@dirs[0..$#dir-5]; print File::Spec->catdir(@dirs2)."\n";')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am not familiar with perl.  Any alternatives using awk, sed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Michael - no, you can't do that in awk or sed - the logic is encapsulated in Perl `File::Spec` library and the array slice syntax (`@dirs2=@dirs[0..$#dir-5]`). However, you don't need to **know** perl to use this answer - just copy/paste the last line into your shell script as-is (after testing of course) and change "5" to your desired depth.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas other than putting in a for loop?

In shells, you can't avoid the loop, because traditionally they do not support regexp, but glob matching instead. And glob patterns do not support the any sort of repeat counters.

And BTW, simplest way is to do it in shell is: `echo $(cd $PWD/../.. && echo $PWD)` where the `/../..` makes it strip two levels.

With tiny bit of Perl that would be:

```
perl -e '$ENV{PWD} =~ m@^(.*)(/[^/]+){2}$@ && print $1,"\n"'
```

The `{2}` in the Perl's regular expression is the number of directory entries to strip. Or making it configurable:

```
N=2
perl -e '$ENV{PWD} =~ m@^(.*)(/[^/]+){'$N'}$@ && print $1,"\n"'
```

One can also use Perl's [split()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), [join()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) and [splice()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) for the purpose, e.g.:

```
perl -e '@a=split("/", $ENV{PWD}); print join("/", splice(@a, 0, -2)),"\n"'
```

where `-2` says that from the path the last two entries has to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Two levels above the script directory:

```
echo "$(readlink -f -- "$(dirname -- "$0")/../..")"
```

All the quoting and `--` are to avoid problems with tricky paths.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses the actual full path to the perl script itself ... TIMTOWTDI
You could just easily replace the $RunDir with the path you would like to start with ...

```
        #resolve the run dir where this scripts is placed
        $0 =~ m/^(.*)(\\|\/)(.*)\.([a-z]*)/; 
        $RunDir = $1 ; 
        #change the \'s to /'s if we are on Windows
        $RunDir =~s/\\/\//gi ; 
        my @DirParts = split ('/' , $RunDir) ; 
        for (my $count=0; $count < 4; $count++) {   pop @DirParts ;     }

        $confHolder->{'ProductBaseDir'} = $ProductBaseDir ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to work your way up until whatever condition is desired

```
WORKDIR=$PWD
until test -d "$WORKDIR/infra/codedeploy"; do
  # get the full path of the script

  WORKDIR=$(dirname $WORKDIR)
done
```